# Searching for a factor to define the length of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Currently having a hard time wrapping my head around an easy math problem.
I am basically looking for `b`, when `a` is given. I think there should be some factor defining `b` as a product of the factor and `a`; I think something around `0.6`.

Sorry for the question name; had a hard time coming up with one.

[image: Image showing the rough estimation of the math problem]

Comment: The triangle side lengths are $1:1:\sqrt2$, so the shorter sides are $\frac{\sqrt 2}2b$. Therefore you have $a = \frac{\sqrt 2}2b+b$.

Comment: Rearranging that last equation, $b\left(1+\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right) = a$, which means $b = \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sqrt 2}2}\right)a$. That factor is indeed close to $0.6$. We can still clean it up: first, multiply top and bottom by $2$ to get $b=\left(\frac2{2+\sqrt2}\right)a$. Next, multiply top and bottom by $2-\sqrt2$ to get $$b=\left(\frac{2(2-\sqrt2)}{(2+\sqrt2)(2-\sqrt2)}\right)a.$$ What happens when you expand the denominator?

Comment: Oh man, so obvious. 

Oh. Denominator is just 2 then.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's right, and then the $2$ cancels with the $2$ in the numerator, leaving simply $b = (2-\sqrt2)a \approx 0.586a$. Glad to help.